# Resize array by index

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, indexing

I got an array like ...

```
let array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

..., an start-index `let start = 2` and an end-index `let end = 5`.

I'd like to resize the array starting with index **startIndex** and ending with **endIndex** like this example:

```
start = 2;
end = 3;

let result = [2, 3]
```

---

```
start = 2;
end = 2;

let result = [2]
```

---

```
start = 0;
end = 8;

let result = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

This snippet below is what I've got so far. But obviously there are some issues:

```js
let array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

let start = 2
let end = 3
array.splice(0, start);
array.splice(end, array.length);

console.log(array)
```

Comment: The parameters for `.splice(...)` are `indexToStartAt, numberOfElementsToRemove, [elements, to, add]`. In your case you'd want to specify `end - start + 1` for the index to start at when doing the second splice. Or use `.slice(...)` like recommended by the other answerers.

Comment: do you need to keep the same array reference?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.slice()` to get a new array:

```js
const array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

const start = 2
const end = 3

const result = array.slice(start, end + 1);

console.log(result)
```

And if you want to mutate the original array directly, you can combine that with `Array.splice()`:

```js
const array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

const start = 2
const end = 3

array.splice(0, array.length, ...array.slice(start, end + 1));

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.slice(start,end)` and increase `end` by one, since you want it to be inclusive.

```js
let array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

let start = 2
let end = 3
var result = array.slice(start, end+1);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

when you splice result array (array after you splice first time) with the index of the actual array [array in question], you got that output
please look at the following code. Run this code and see you will understand

```
let array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

let start = 2
let end = 3

array.splice(0,start);

//After splice this is result array [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13] 

console.log(array);

//If you splice again with end=3 index you get the result array as [2, 3, 4]. 
// To get your desired output as array you should work on array after you splice first time

array.splice(2,array.length);

console.log(array);
```

I hope this explains what happen with your code. As a reminder about splice method.
 The splice() method adds/removes items to/from an array, and returns the removed item(s).

Syntax:

array.splice(index, howmany, item1, ....., itemX)

Answer (score 0):

You could take [`Array#copyWithin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/copyWithin) and adjust the `length` of the array.

```js
var start = 2,
    end = 5,
    array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];

array.copyWithin(0, start, end + 1).length = end - start + 1;

console.log(array);
```